# Error con exportación de archivos PhpExcel

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpexcel

Buen día, me sale un error que no entiendo al usar `Php Excel`, alguien me puede ayudar.

> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Exception: Cell coordinate can not be zero-length string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Unificada\library\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:591 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Unificada\library\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Style.php(228): PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Unificada\view\Load.php(164): PHPExcel_Style->applyFromArray(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Unificada\library\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 591

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
require_once '../library/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require '../controller/Conexion.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
 $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("")
                               ->setLastModifiedBy("")
                               ->setTitle("Office 2010 XLSX Documento de Excel")
                               ->setSubject("Office 2010 XLSX Documento de Excel")
                               ->setDescription("Documento de Excel para Office 2010 XLSX.")
                               ->setKeywords("office 2010 openxml php")
                               ->setCategory("Archivo con resultado de Excel");

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:E1');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                ->setCellValue('A1', 'PROD ESC')
                                ->setCellValue('A2', 'Identificacion TXT')
                                ->setCellValue('B2', 'Producto')
                                ->setCellValue('C2', 'Credito')
                                ->setCellValue('D2', 'Credito_2')
                                ->setCellValue('E2', 'Saldo Capital');

$boldArray = array('font' => array('bold' => true,), 'alignment' => array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:E2')->applyFromArray($boldArray);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(30);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(30);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(30);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `prod esc`";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$cel = 3;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            $A1 = $row['IdentificacionTXT'];
                            $B1 = $row['Producto'];
                            $C1 = $row['Credito'];
                            $D1 = $row['Credito2'];
                            $E1 = $row['SaldoCapital'];

                            $a = "A" . $cel;
                            $b = "B" . $cel;
                            $c = "C" . $cel;
                            $d = "D" . $cel;
                            $e = "E" . $cel;

                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                    ->setCellValue($a, $A1)
                                    ->setCellValue($b, $B1)
                                    ->setCellValue($c, $C1)
                                    ->setCellValue($d, $D1)
                                    ->setCellValue($e, $E1);

                            $cel += 1;
                        }

$rango = "A2:'$e'";
$styleArray = array('font' => array('name' => 'Arial', 'size' => 12), 'borders' => array('allborders' => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN, 'color' => array('argb' => 'FFF'))));
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($rango)->applyFromArray($styleArray);

                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Prod esc');
                        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

                        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="reporte.xls"');
                        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
                        header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

                        header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
                        header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
                        header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
                        header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

                        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
                        $objWriter->save('php://output');
                        exit;
                        ?>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Seria bueno que colocaras el código que tienes hasta el momento para que te puedan ayudar mucho mas fácil.

Comment: listo ya lo muestro.

Comment: En el proyecto Github de [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) se indica que esta librería es obsoleta desde 2015 y se recomienda migrar a **[PHPSpreadSheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)**

Comment: Si pero yo la he estado usando y no me ha puesto problemas.

Comment: @Kygo y entonces esto no es un problema??? el detalle no es que te de problema es que ya no desean darle soporte ni agregar documentación adicional. si te pasas a la nueva libreria externa y le estas dando un uso MVC / OOP de seguro que migrar sera muy sencillo.

Comment: Pero yo si había escuchado que ya no iban a sacar mas versiones pero que la ultima no era obsoleta y que PHPSpreadSheet aun no sacan versión oficial.

Comment: Ese error se te presenta cuando estas salvando o abriendo un archivo?

Comment: Cuando ingreso a la pagina donde voy a exportar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tipo de error que estás teniendo empezó a ser reportado por algunos usuarios en el apartado `issues` de la librería PHPExcel **desde el año 2012** ([ver por ejemplo aquí](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/28)) ¡Estamos hablando de cinco años atrás!.

Teniendo en cuenta lo que afirman los creadores de PHPExcel aquí:

> PHPExcel last version, 1.8.1, was released in 2015. The project is no
> longer maintained and should not be used anymore.
>
> All users should migrate to its direct successor PhpSpreadsheet, or
> another alternative.
>
> In a few months, the GitHub project will be marked as archived, so
> everything will be read-only.
>
> ---
>
> La última versión de PHPExcel, 1.8.1, se lanzó en 2015. **El proyecto
> ya no se mantiene y ya no se debe usar**.
>
> **Todos los usuarios deberían migrar a su sucesora directa, [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet),  u otra alternativa.**
>
> En unos meses, el proyecto GitHub se marcará como archivado, por lo
> que todo será de solo lectura.
>
> <sub>[PHPExcel en Github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)</sub>

Es evidente que **no tiene ningún sentido tratar de hacer funcionar un código obsoleto**, el cual, aunque funcione hoy es muy probable que te falle mañana, cuando haya una nueva actualización de Excel o de PHP.

### Solución

Lo que ellos mismos dicen:

**Todos los usuarios deberían migrar a su sucesora directa, PhpSpreadsheet, u otra alternativa.**

Cabe destacar que PhpSpreadsheet no está en fase beta, ya existe como una librería totalmente funcional:

- [PhpSpreadsheet  en Github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)
- [Documentación oficial completa sobre la librería](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

Comment: Gracias me toco obligatoria mente cambiar las librerías, gracias por tu ayuda, aunque tengo una duda, están los mismos archivos que de phpExcel?

Comment: @Kygo si te refieres a los archivos internos de la librería es muy improbable que sean los mismos... de todos modos, en Github puedes ver el contenido de una y otra librería.

Comment: Entonces como hago para pasarme de phpexcel a PhpSpreadsheet?, porque yo ya tengo cosas que me funcionan con phpexcel, Por favor.

Comment: @Kygo, está explicado en la documentación. [Aquí hay un ejemplo inicial](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#hello-world) y en el apartado llamado *Learn by documentation* hay varios enlaces más para aprender los usos básicos de la librería. Por supuesto habrá que instalar la librería, la mejor manera es usando composer.

Comment: Ok gracias por tu apoyo.