# Modificar el tamaño de letra (o el estilo) del título de un gráfico con PHPExcel o PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Al crear un archivo excel con PHPExcel o PHPspreadSheet, quiero modificar el tamaño de letra (o el estilo) del título de un gráfico. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto mi código. El código es correcto, no genera ningún error y los gráficos se imprimen correctamente.

```
$title= new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Title("titulo", null);
$title->getFont()->setSize(10);

$chart = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart(
    'chart1',   // name
    $title,       // title
    $legend,       // legend
    $plotArea,  // plotArea
    true,       // plotVisibleOnly
    0,          // displayBlanksAs
    $xAxisLabel,       // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel        // yAxisLabel
);
```

Clase Title:

```
<?php

namespace PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Font;

class Title
{
    /**
     * Title Caption.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $caption;

    /**
     * Title Layout.
     *
     * @var Layout
     */
    private $layout;

     /**
     * Title Font
     *
     * @var Font
     */
    private $font;


    /**
     * Create a new Title.
     *
     * @param null|mixed $caption
     * @param null|Layout $layout
    */
    public function __construct($caption = null, Layout $layout = null)
    {
        $this->caption = $caption;
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->font = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Font();
    }

    /**
     * Get caption.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCaption()
    {
       return $this->caption;
    }

    /**
     * Set caption.
     *
     * @param string $caption
     *
     * @return Title
     */
    public function setCaption($caption)
    {
       $this->caption = $caption;

       return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Layout.
     *
     * @return Layout
     */
    public function getLayout()
    {
        return $this->layout;
    }


    /**
     * Get font
     *
     * @return Font
     */
    public function getFont() {
        return $this->font;
    }
    /**
     * Set font
     *
     * @param Font $font
     * @return Title
     */
    public function setFont( PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Font $font = null)  {
        $this->font = $font;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

He ecnontrado este post:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/688
Siguiendo las indicaciones del post he modificado la clase ***chart.php*** , la clase ***StringTable.php*** y la clase **Title**.

Classes/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/Chart.php

```
private function writeTitle(Title $title = null, $objWriter)
    if ((is_array($caption)) && (count($caption) > 0)) {
        $caption = $caption[0];
    }
    //$this->getParentWriter()->getWriterPart('stringtable')->writeRichTextForCharts($objWriter, $caption, 'a');
    $pRichText =new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\RichText();
    $pRichText->createTextRun($caption);
    $elements = $pRichText->getRichTextElements();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $element->setFont($title->getFont());
    }
    $this->getParentWriter()->getWriterPart('stringtable')->writeRichTextForCharts($objWriter, $pRichText, 'a');
    $objWriter->endElement();
    $objWriter->endElement();
```

En la clase StringTable, he añadido las lineas de código necesarias para modificar el tamaño de la letra del título del gráfico, puesto que no había ninguna linea relacionada con el tamaño de la letra. Para que no haya errores, he puesto directamente a mano que tenga una tamaño de 10pt ($objWriter->writeAttribute('val', 10))

Classes/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/StringTable.php

```
 /**
 * Write Rich Text.
 *
 * @param XMLWriter $objWriter XML Writer
 * @param RichText|string $pRichText text string or Rich text
 * @param string $prefix Optional Namespace prefix
 */
public function writeRichTextForCharts(XMLWriter $objWriter, $pRichText = null, $prefix = null)
       //size Font
        $objWriter->startElement($prefix . 'sz');
        $objWriter->writeAttribute('val', 10);
        $objWriter->endElement();
```

Por defecto, el tamaño de la letra de los títulos de los gráficos es de 18pt. Quiero que sean de 10pt.

Comment: Ya que no conozco PHP, una búsqueda rápida me llevó a esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14243679/4092887). Si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema, vota positivamente a la respuesta, de lo contrario, puedes buscar en Google usando el término `phpexcel change font size`. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte pero necesito modificar los estilos del titulo del gráfico, no los estilos de la celda. Respecto a la búsqueda que has mencionado, es demasiado ambigua.

Comment: ivan.depi ¿has consultado la documentación de phpspreadsheet?

Comment: Si, claro. No pone nada.

Comment: Recomendaría que implementes una solución basada en la librería `phpspreadsheet`, ya que `phpexcel` es una librería obsoleta y que ya no es mantenida ni actualizada ([dejo aquí la nota traducida y el enlace original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128583/29967)) ahora reviso la documentación de `phpspreadsheet` a ver si puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Iván, prueba haciendo algo como esto: `$tuObjeto->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setSize(10);`, asumiendo que el título se encuentra al principio de la hoja (`A1`). Creo que la lectura de *[Exploring PhpSpreadsheet's Formatting Capabilities](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/exploring-phpspreadsheets-formatting-capabilities.html)* te puede ser de gran ayuda. En cuanto a tu código, no entiendo por qué tienes una clase `Title` si ya la librería tiene todas esas clases incorporadas y sólo tienes que usarlas adecuadamente. ¿No estarás intentando reinventar la rueda inútilmente?

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por tu aporte y por tu tiempo.  Si observas el código que he pegado, veras que la clase `Title`  pertenece a la librería PhpSpreadsheet.  Si tienes alguna duda de esto puedes verlo aqui https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet. Ademas si miras la documentacion de PhpSpreadsheet  veras que la manera de aplicar un estilo a un titulo de un gráfico no es esta: **$tuObjeto->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setSize(10)**, sino está **$title= new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Title("titulo", null);
$title->getFont()->setSize(10)** Por lo tanto esto no soluciona mi pregunta.

Comment: Iván, revisa la respuesta que he escrito. Al mostrar una clase `Title`pensé que estabas implementando tú esa clase (no veo que sentido tiene que la compartas en la pregunta, ya que es una clase de la librería). Lo que tienes que hacer es seguir las indicaciones de la documentación para configurar los estilos. Agradecería que me muestres el enlace donde dices que explican que la forma de hacerlo es esta: `$title= new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Title("titulo", null); $title->getFont()->setSize(10);`

Comment: Ahí tienes todas las funciones de la clase Chart -> https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.2.1/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Chart/Chart.html que influye la función `setTitle`

Comment: @A.Cedano agradecería que me muestres el enlace donde dices que explican que la forma de hacerlo es esta  `$tuObjeto->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setSize(10)`

Comment: Iván, revisa el [enlace al inicio de mi respuesta](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#styles) y también [el que pongo al final](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128583/29967), en la recomendación. Agradecería que me digas si has probado a hacerlo así y digas si ha funcionado o no. No puedes descartar una respuesta sin probarla.

Comment: Si, está probado. La celda que pongo cambia de estilos, pero el gráfico sigue saliendo con el titulo  a un tamaño de letra de 18pt. Gracias.

Comment: Iván, asumo que si construyes bien el gráfico, el título efectivamente estaría en la celda `A1` y el estilo se podría cambiar normalmente (como se indica en mi respuesta). Revisando la doc no encuentro ninguna otra forma de poder hacerlo. ¿Estás construyendo el gráfico de la forma correcta? [Aquí hay un ejemplo de código](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/382#issuecomment-392456449)  donde se setea el título en la celda `A1`, y hay que usar `setIncludeCharts`, como muestra [esta respuesta](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/382#issuecomment-394626917).

Comment: El gráfico se construye bien, correctamente, pero hace caso omiso al la edición de estilos del titulo del gráfico. Recuerda que yo no quiero setear el titulo de una celda, sino el del gráfico. Esto se hace configurando los parámetros del gráfico, no los de la celda.

Comment: Entiendo eso Iván, pero en la doc no habla nada de esto y me parece muy extraño, por lo que intuyo que hay que hacerlo por el procedimiento normal que explican sobre los estilos. De lo contrario, la librería tendría un método propio para cambiar los estilos del título.

Comment: Si viniese en la documentación, no hubiera creado la pregunta aquí. Lo he intentado de mil maneras. Ahora estoy rugando en la librería para modificarlo.

Comment: [He preguntado a los creadores del proyecto en Github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/847), veremos qué dicen al respecto.

Comment: @ivan.depi, ¿estas usando `JpGraph` para renderizar los charts? Si la respuesta es si, intenta agregar esta línea `$this->graph->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,10);` en el archivo `PhpSpreadsheet/Chart/Renderer/JpGraph.php` en la linea `186`, **antes** de `$this->graph->title->Set($title);` ([ver codigo fuente](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Chart/Renderer/JpGraph.php#L186))

Comment: @Marcos Muchas gracias, no estoy utilizando JpGraph pero lo tomaré como opción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido solucionarlo. Para ello he tenido que modificar clases de la librería Phpspreadsheet.
En el  código que añadí al formular la pregunta, hay que modificar la clase StringTable.php.

Adjunto el código correcto de dicha clase.

```
Classes/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/StringTable.php

 /**
 * Write Rich Text.
 *
 * @param XMLWriter $objWriter XML Writer
 * @param RichText|string $pRichText text string or Rich text
 * @param string $prefix Optional Namespace prefix
 */
 public function writeRichTextForCharts(XMLWriter $objWriter, $pRichText = null, $prefix = null)
       //size Font
       $objWriter->writeAttribute('sz', $element->getFont()->getSize() * 100 );
```

Comment: Creo que podrías plantearlo a los creadores del proyecto como *feature request*, para que lo agreguen en una próxima actualización del proyecto y así no tengas que modificar los archivos  manualmente.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, además, yo tambien lo voy a subir a github.

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el tamaño de la fuente, según explica la [documentación de PHPSpreadSheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#styles), puedes hacerlo directamente en la celda donde se encuentra el título (`A1` en este caso).

El proceso sería el siguiente:

- Obtener la hoja activa con `getActiveSheet()`
- Obtener el estilo de la celda (o rango de celdas) con `getStyle()`
- Obtener la fuente de ese estilo con `getFont()`
- Finalmente, setear el tamaño de la fuente ya obtenida con `setSize`

Siguiendo los pasos antes mencionados, el código sería este:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(10);
```

Aquí `$spreadsheet` representa la referencia al objeto SpreadSheet que se ha creado.

La documentación también explica que en `getStyle` se puede incluir un rango de celdas, por ejemplo: `getStyle('A1:A10')`

---

Otra forma de hacerlo sería aplicando un estilo con varios componentes mediante `applyFromArray`. Esto funcionaría como los CSS y es recomendable en situaciones en las que haya que aplicar varios estilos (sería como tener clases CSS).

Por ejemplo aquí aplicamos un tamaño grande de fuente y en negritas:

```
$styleTitle = [
    'font' => [
        'bold' => true,
        'size' => 20
    ]
];

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleTitle);
```

Este sería un estilo simplificado. Se pueden crear estilos más complejos relativos a todos los elementos posibles (no solamente la fuente), sino también los bordes, colores de fondo, etc. Y, se pueden aplicar también a rangos de celdas.

---

> ### Recomendaciones
>
> Finalmente, recomiendo no renunciar a PHPSpreadSheet en favor de
> PHPExcel ya que esta última es una librería obsoleta, que no es
> mantenida desde hace ya algunos años. Cuando se buscan tutoriales o
> incluso preguntas aquí o en el homólogo inglés, encontraremos miles de
> preguntas/respuestas basadas en PHPExcel porque ésta fue durante
> muchos años la librería de referencia. Sin embargo hoy día su uso no
> es aconsejado por su obsolescencia <sup>1</sup>.
>
> La lectura de [*Exploring PhpSpreadsheet's Formatting Capabilities*](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/exploring-phpspreadsheets-formatting-capabilities.html) puede ser quizá de gran ayuda para este caso.
>
> ---
>
> #### Notas:
>
> 1. En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128583/29967) he traducido la nota que informa sobre este asunto, haciendo referencia al enlace original.

Comment: Estas poniendo el código para cambiar los estilos de una celda, en lugar de poner el código para cambiar los estilos del titulo de un gráfico. Por favor vea https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.2.1/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Chart/Chart.html

Comment: Hola! Creo que Iván no se refiere a cambiar el estilo de una celda, mas bien para cambiar el estilo a un titulo dentro de un gráfico. Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score -2):

utiliza la función setSize() para aplicarle el tamaño de letra.

aquí un ejemplo:

```
$this->font
        ->setName('Arial')
        ->setSize(15);
```

Comment: No funciona. Ya intenté esto: $titulo->getFont()->setSize(10);