# Convertir un archivo plano a Excel con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, tablas, phpexcel

Buen día, tengo problemas en un proyecto nuevo para mi ya que no soy experto en PHP, he visto muchos tutoriales para pasar Grids a Excel sin problemas pero no se como pasar un archivo plano a Excel.

Quiero saber si hay alguna manera de pasar un archivo plano y convertirlo a Excel.

Por ahora solo he logrado subir el archivo al servidor mediante un text y un button.

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar la pregunta y añadir el código con lo que hayas intentado? De esta forma la comunidad podrá guiarte y ayudarte en caso de que estés atascado o tengas errores que no logres resolver de ninguna manera y no termina cerrada tu pregunta. Te invito a leer como preguntar: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] y a hacer el recorrido: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour]. Saludos.

Comment: Simplemente señalar que PHPExcel es obsoleto desde 2015 y no continuará a ser mantenido ni actualizado. Ver más detalles en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128583/29967). Allí están también los enlaces den PHPSpreadSheets, que es la biblioteca recomendada en sustitución de PHPExcel. Si continúas a usarlo puede que te encuentres con escollos en tus proyectos.