# Desbordamiento de memoria en PHP

Tags: php, web

Hola compañeros yo nuevamente con una duda grandísima, estoy escribiendo en excel desde php, el codigo ya me estaba funcionando sin problemas, este es el codigo:

```
*****require 'excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    // Creamos un objeto PHPExcel
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('machotecotizacion.xlsx');
    // Indicamos que se pare en la hoja uno del libro
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    for($i = 0,$size = count($a), $fil=15 ; $i<$size; $i+1){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$fil, $a[$i]);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$fil, $a[$i+1]);
        $fil=$fil+1;
    }
    //Modificamos los valoresde las celdas A2, B2 Y C2
    /*$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B15', $a[0]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F15', $a[1]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B16', $a[2]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F16', $a[3]);*/
    //Guardamos los cambios
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save("Archivo_salida.xlsx");*****
```

me generaba mi excel sin problemas, pero ahora cuando lo ejecuto me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al principio modifique la variable memory_ini de php venia con el valor de 512M y lo aumente a 1024M después lo seguí aumentando hasta 4096M pero sigue saliendo el mismo error, alguien puede ayudarme a darle solución.

Comment: Puede que estés exagerando con los registros y la generación del excel.

Comment: Debes depurar el código para encontrar la fuga de memoria, de lo contrario solo estarás parchando el problema. Usa xdebug es lo mejor para este tipo de problemas

Comment: Lo primero es que estás usando una herramienta obsoleta y que ya no es actualizada ni mantenida (me refiero a `PHPExcel`, [ver + aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128583/29967)). Te recomendaría que uses a su sucesor, que es [`PHPSpreadSheet`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). Si habiendo migrado el código sigues con problemas de memoria, verifica que lo que estás procesando no es excesivamente grande, en cuyo caso convendría fragmentar ese contenido.